While working on a MERN project, i am stuck on a problem while i try to get data from the register page from the form, the Axios is giving error
While working on a MERN project, i am stuck on a problem while i try to get data from the register page from the form, the Axios is giving error. I am trying to send data to the database but i am stuck on this problem. i tried to refresh my app.js file but still i am unable to identify the cause.
import "./register.scss";
import { Link, useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import axios from "axios";
import { useState } from "react";
import apiRequest from "../../lib/apiRequest";

function Register() {

  const [error, setError] = useState("")

  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const formData = new FormData(e.target);

    const username = formData.get("username"); 
    const email = formData.get("email"); 
    const password = formData.get("password");

    try {
      const res = await axios.post("http://localhost:5000/api/auth/register", {
        username, email, password
      })
      console.log(res.data);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
      // setError()
    }
  }
  return (
    <div className="registerPage">
      <div className="formContainer">
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
          <h1>Create an Account</h1>
          <input name="username" type="text" placeholder="Username" />
          <input name="email" type="text" placeholder="Email" />
          <input name="password" type="password" placeholder="Password" />
          <button>Register</button>
          <Link to="/login">Do you have an account?</Link>
        </form>
      </div>
      <div className="imgContainer">
        <img src="/bg.png" alt="" />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Register;


and this is the app.js =
import express from "express";
import cors from "cors";
import authRoute from "./routes/auth.route.js"
import postRoute from "./routes/post.route.js"
import cookieParser from "cookie-parser"
const app = express();
app.use(cors({ origin: process.env.CLIENT_URL, credentials:true }));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use("/api/posts", postRoute)
app.use("/api/auth", authRoute);

app.listen(process.env.PORT, ()=>{
    console.log("Server is running");
})


Anyone please try to help me catch this error so that, I can finally finish this project

Check out the Network tab in your browser's dev tools. Check the request and response to see if you can figure out what is happening on a more granular level.
Also, add some try/catch statements to your axios request. There are a few reasons why the request may not be working. It'll help to get a better view on which one that is.

i checked the network tab so when i clicked on the register button its is giving an CORS Error: Origin Resource Sharing Error : PreflightAllowOriginMismatch

Make sure process.env.CLIENT_URL matches your client url exactly. Your server is on port 5000, what port is your client running on? Make sure this your CLIENT_URL environment variable reflects this.

The api endpoint you are trying to call from frontend I think is incomplete.
<Link to="/login">Do you have an account?</Link>

Above is the api endpoint you are calling but there is no such api endpoint in your app.js. Maybe you are intending to call /api/auth/login
<Link to="/api/auth/login">Do you have an account?</Link>


tied it but the problem is still there

Please show the auth.route.js file.
